# Android/Eclipse debugging

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm relatively new to Android development, but I am having some issues with debugging on a new device I am working with.

Previously, I was using a Samsung Nexus S (Google development phone) running Android 4.0.4. When I plug in the USB, I get two notifications: *USB connected*, and *USB debugging connected*. When connected, Eclipse will prompt me to select the device I want to debug with, and I get tons of useful info in my LogCat window.

I recently started using a Samsung Galaxy S4, running Android 4.2.2. I have installed the [USB driver](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/SPH-L720ZKASPR) from Samsung, but when I plug in the USB, I now only get a single notification: *Connected as a media device*. Now when I am running my app through Eclipse, it doesn't prompt me to select a device, and I get almost nothing in my LogCat window.

Can anyone instruct me on what I need to install or configure to get Eclipse to prompt me for the device, and give more detailed logging while debugging? USB debugging is enabled on the phone, in the Developer Options menu.

Comment: Have you set up your new phone with debbuging settings in developer settings? Programmers options - > USB Debgging or somethng like that.

Comment: You should enable developer settings. It's different for JellyBean.

http://www.chriscowley.me.uk/blog/2013/05/29/enable-developer-options-on-android-jellybean/

Comment: USB debugging is already enabled, as I specified in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

a) Have you turned on your Samsung S4 debugging mode

**To activate the USB debugging:**
From idle mode > tap on Menu > Settings > Applications > Development
Check "USB debugging"

b) Have you installed the necessary drivers for Debugging in Eclipse they are not the usual USB Drivers. Have a search on google you will find it
c) After installing reconnect you machine you will that it will mention on your device. Connected for debugging. And you LogCat will start populating

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to set your phone into developer mode by clicking 7 times on Build version. Once this is done, you can check `adb devices` to see online devices connected to your machine. If you see your device, then you are good to go.

[This](http://droidviews.com/2013/how-to-enable-developer-optionsusb-debugging-mode-on-devices-with-android-4-2-jelly-bean/)  link might help.

Comment: It says developer mode has already been turned on. When you say to check adb devices, do you mean in Device Manager on my PC? Because I have already installed the USB driver from Samsung, and in Device Manager, under Android Phone, it recognizes it as Samsung Android ADB Interface.

Comment: Ideally, this should be right path to check for device drivers- ..\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130219\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver. If you do not see the google folder in extra, try updating your android sdk thorough eclipse.

Comment: Then uninstall the current driver and plug the device again. When windows tries to search for driver, select choose from folder and use the earlier path for driver source. I have had exact problem in the past which was fixed by this. Somehow it doesnt recognize the manufacturer's driver.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a tablet and a similar program. I found that if you forced the usb-sharing program to quit by using teh applications manager then eclipse would then find the phone. it is by no means a long term solution but at least you get to see the logcat.